# How to create a interative form after windows logon

Tags: windows, registry, banner, winlogon

I would like to create a kind of banner that will appear after logging in to Windows and will only be closed after the user read the message and click on "OK ".

I would also like to save this information in the machine registry.

Is it possible to do that? If so, how could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, CredentialProvider don't have any meaningful control after leaving `GetSerialization` method.

Your CredentialProvider will be called for `UnAdvise` method, but I'm think it is not good idea to do some job inside this method.